# WordPress importer plugin

Tags: xml, wordpress, import

I am trying to import an .xml backup from an old WordPress to another WordPress installation. 
I have used the WordPress Imported plugin to import my back up .xml file. It presents me with the screen that allows me to match the authors etc and then after I click import, it says there is a system error. File does not exist.

I had some issues with the blog lately so I thought better to re install the version all together to the 3.5.1. During this process I also updated the WordPress Importer 0.6.1 version as well.

Trying to import  my back up .xml again but now I get just an empty page, nothing is happening.

I can confirm that I have edited the maximum file size and memory size so thats not an issue.

Any help, please!!

Comment: Try to on your error using `ini_set("display_errors",1);` in your index file.

Comment: Sorry, not quite sure what you mean or need to do?

Comment: Ok, now I am getting this error "Fatal error: Class 'DOMDocument' not found in /home/blog.name.com/web/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/wordpress-importer/parsers.php on line 61"

Comment: Ok so you need to install `dom` first . try `sudo apt-get install php5-dom`

Comment: Hi Rikesh, I am not that experienced with linux and commands. What excactly I need to do if you can guide me please. I can connect into my blog server as root via ssh, then what? just add your command?

Comment: yes just add the above commend. it will install dom in your pc.

Comment: that didn't work. I found somewhere else, I need to add this yum install php-xml

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the issue on my **4.7.2** on `ec2` and `rds`.

### How I found the problem

I added this to my `wp-config.php` file:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
/**
 * Just a convenient check so you can leave the next few lines unchanged
 * for next time you need debugging, and just switch true/false above.
 */
if (WP_DEBUG) {
    //Handle all errors regardless of error level
    ini_set('error_reporting', -1);
    //Display errors directly in the browser
    ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
}
```

The settings above enabled debug mode for me to find the error that the OP got.

### What I did to fix the problem

Then I looked at another WordPress issue tracker and found that I needed to run:

```
sudo yum install php-xml
```

This command installs the `php xml` library so that WordPress can actually read the `xml` file.

Answer (score 0):

@Rikesh's method in your comments should work, but if you're still having trouble using the WordPress importer, I've had a lot of luck with the [WP Migrate DB plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-migrate-db/) for the database used in tandem with just FTPing the files over to the new server.